# cant float things without interrapting eachothers

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    font-family: arial;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav{
    background-color: maroon;
    width: 14%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    
}
.body{
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    
}
.login{
    background-color: maroon;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csspart.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">nav</div>
        <div class="body">body</div>
        <div class="login">login</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a problem with floating a 100% height and navbar to left and a 100% sign up div to the right and body between them. i tried some position 's but I believe missing something with positioning. hope somebody knows what I miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float: left` on all your 3 div's and change this rule

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
*{
  font-family: arial;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;

}
.body{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 66%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;

}
.login{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csspart.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="login"></div>
    
    </body>


</html>
```

---

If you want to add for example a footer, do like this, using a wrapper, which as well clear the float

```css
*{
  font-family: arial;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap:after{
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.nav{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;        /* when use padding/border this is needed or else the     */
}                                /* width has to be changed to keep its total size of 14%  */
.body{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 66%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;

}
.login{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
}
.footer{
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">Blablablablablabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="login"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

---

Now, for equal column size beyond the viewport, float isn't a good choice anymore, `flex` is, so here is a more practical solution.

```css
*{
  font-family: arial;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.nav{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 14%;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;        /* when use padding/border this is needed or else the     */
}                                /* width has to be changed to keep its total size of 14%  */
.body{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 66%;
}
.login{
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 20%;
}
.footer{
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">Blablablablablabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </div>
  <div class="body">
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content last<br> 
    
  </div>
  <div class="login"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

---

If you can't use `flex`, use `display: table`

```css
*{
  font-family: arial;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.nav{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 14%;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;        /* when use padding/border this is needed or else the     */
}                                /* width has to be changed to keep its total size of 14%  */
.body{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 66%;
}
.login{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 20%;
}
.footer{
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">Blablablablablabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </div>
  <div class="body">
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content <br> 
 Content last<br> 
    
  </div>
  <div class="login"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: i just tried it and doesnt seem to work -_- . actually the "%" sign seem to work wrong completaly

Comment: @AgilAsadi As you can see it work in my answer, so which part of mine didn't you copy?

Comment: whow hilarious :D it works perfectly now . did u change anything else ?

Comment: @AgilAsadi Nope, just added the note about the `body` rule

Comment: awwww. u r my hero. im working on this styling for 3 days now. had a different design but i have been trying to change it to better version. been failing and i was about to throw the PC out the window

Comment: @LGSon, sorry for saying but don't you think you should add clear after float:left as in example it has fixed width but what if not?hope you will get my point.. :)

Comment: @AgilAsadi Of course you should, if you have more contents that need that, though since you didn't, I didn't add any clearing

Comment: @LGSon, lol i asked the question about clear as i have idea but seems Agil is totally new for float so i said  you should mention in your answer so Agil can get more detail about float and clear :)

Comment: well. i learned css a while ago but forgot so many things. btw i guess the reason u ask me to add clear after float is that when i chnage the size of page it stacks up ?

Comment: @AgilAsadi Updated my answer with an explanation

Comment: yeah i see it now. but what if write something in .nav than give it some padding. does the text go under the .body so some part of it is not visible ?

Comment: yeah it tottaly goes under the .body class . if you write something on .nav class than give it padding and change the size of window by scrolling and the part of the text crashes the body -_-

Comment: @AgilAsadi I updated again to show how to fix that, check `.nav` rule

Comment: yeah i see what u did. but delete the space and write smthing like with 12 letters and it will crash. try this blablablabla

Comment: @LGSON since im trying to creat a navbar there. some words are longer than the others and i want the size respond to the window size

Comment: @lgson give this padding "padding: 8px 16px 8px 1px;"

Comment: @AgilAsadi Updated again, to fix blablablabla by adding `word-break: break-word;` ... Now, to have the size respond to the window is a completely new question, so accept this answer, and post a new with that requirement.

Comment: @LGSon i found another problem if u r still interesteed in helping with it :D the problem is when you add too many content in body that takes more space than it offers until the footer. it bumps out of body and even out of footer. it is same for all three divs

Comment: @LGSon mate u r just whow. why r u even doing this ? why r u helping me while i do nothing for u ? is this some kind of joy ? r u a psychopath ? or is there anything u gain ? :D

Comment: @AgilAsadi Little bit psycho, little bit insanity, much joy :) ... by solving other peoples questions, you help your self, as problem solving increase the way to think out of the box ... and at some point I get the favor back from someone else here ... so we all win :)

Comment: @LGSon so u removed all the float s ? and the display table ?

Comment: @LGSon whow i dont think i understood it all. what hapened to floats, heights, warp:after

Comment: @AgilAsadi I removed floats (and `wrap:after` as it is only needed for floats) as it is actually not the best way to do layout, so I posted the `flex`. If you want to target older browsers, like IE8/9, they dont support `flex`, hence the `display: table` variant.